# Framer Motion - Opacity transition works in development, but not when deployed

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

I have simple opacity transitions between pages in React using Framer Motion. The motion.div for all of the pages looks like this:

```
<motion.div exit={{ opacity: 0 }} animate={{ opacity: 1 }} initial={{ opacity: 0 }}>

(div contents)

</motion.div>
```

I have a div - #div-main-menu - within the motion.div that is supposed to have a constant opacity of 80%. This setup works fine in development (transitioning from 0 to 100% opacity), but when I build my project and deploy it to my server, the #div-main-menu only transitions to 1% opacity (aka pretty much invisible). I am confused as to why this only happens when deployed and not in development, and am wondering how I can fix it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do:

```
import { useCycle } from "framer";
//define variable
const [animate, cycle] = useCycle(
    { opacity: 1 },
    { opacity: 0 }
);

<motion.div animate={animate} onTap={() => cycle()}>

(div contents)

</motion.div>
```

If you have this <motion.div> everywhere, I recommend to create a constant you import in each file:

```
export function yourFunctionName({content}){
  const [animate, cycle] = useCycle(
    { opacity: 1 },
    { opacity: 0 }
  );
  return (
    <motion.div animate={animate} onTap={() => cycle()}>

    {content}

    </motion.div>
  );
}
```

Then you cant add import of yourFunctionName to your import, `import {yourFunctionName} from "../../path";`

and use `<yourFunctionName> Some text... </yourFunctionName>` component each file.